# Как можно сократить код js

Tags: javascript, css

```
    $('.cat-parent:nth-child(1').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '0 14px 24px rgba(82,56,115, 0.3)');
}, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '');
});
    $('.cat-parent:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '0 14px 24px rgba(120, 134, 38, 0.3)');
}, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '');
});
    $('.cat-parent:nth-child(3)').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '0 14px 24px rgba(218, 113, 0, 0.3)');
}, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '');
});
    $('.cat-parent:nth-child(4)').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '0 14px 24px rgba(2, 84, 184, 0.3)');
}, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '');
});
    $('.cat-parent:nth-child(5)').hover(function() {
    // навели мышь на элемент
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '0 14px 24px rgba(73, 89, 21, 0.3)');
}, function() {
    // убрали мышь с элемента
    $('header').css('box-shadow', '');
});


});
```

Когда наводишься на пункт меню, меняется тень в шапки, сделано через nth-child потому что привязка в wordrpess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, вроде максимально сократил:

```
var cb=val=>{
    return function(){
        $('header').css('box-shadow',val)
    }
}
$('.cat-parent:lt(6)').hover(
    cb('0 14px 24px rgba(120, 134, 38, 0.3)'),
    cb('')
);
```

Упс, не заметил, что цвета меняются, тогда так:

```
var cb=val=>{
    return function(){
        $('header').css('box-shadow',val)
    }
}
['82, 56, 115','120, 134, 38','218, 113, 0','2, 84, 184','73, 89, 21'].forEach((v,k)=>{
    $(`.cat-parent:nth-child(${k+1})`).hover(
        cb(`0 14px 24px rgba(${v}, 0.3)`),
        cb('')
    )
})
```

И для пущего перфекционизма с моими новыми знаниями:

```
var cb=val=>function(){
    $('header').css('box-shadow',val)
}
['82, 56, 115','120, 134, 38','218, 113, 0','2, 84, 184','73, 89, 21'].forEach((v,k)=>{
    $(`.cat-parent:nth-child(${k+1})`).hover(
        cb(`0 14px 24px rgba(${v}, 0.3)`),
        cb('')
    )
})
```

Comment: Цвет тени разный. Зачем такое жуткое смешение "старого" и "нового" синтаксисов?

Comment: @MedvedevDev Точно, не заметил. И между старым и новым синтаксисом есть существенные различия, которые стоит тут учитывать, потому и смешение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, только пришлось продублировать первую тень, потому что он начинал со второй тени и не давал последней

Comment: Тут его учитывать смысла никакого, на сколько я могу судить, если вы напишете `const cb=val=>()=>{$('header').css('box-shadow',val)}` ничего не изменится

Comment: @ArtemFomkin это я косякнул и уже исправил, используй новый вариант.

Comment: ага увидел  что изменили, теперь отлично работает, спасибо большое

Comment: @MedvedevDev тут суть в том, что обработчик события передаёт элемент на котором событие затриггерилось в коллбэк функцию this объектом. Вот этот новый формат функций (забыл название его) наследует this объект из родительского скопа и не имеет своего, так что в дальнейшем могут возникнуть проблемы, если развивать этот код. Кстати не знал, что можно не использовать return и фигурные скобки в новом формате функции, счас попробую повоспроизводить.

Comment: Так вы и не используете контекст, соответственно можно не смешивать обычные и стрелочные функции, а учитывать на ранней стадии во что это все может в итоге развиться - плохой паттерн, код должен решать конкретные задачи не больше не меньше.

Comment: Больше 5 пунктов меню не будет. Еще хотел спросить, при клике на меню, пункт получает класс .active и переходит на страницу где есть слева каталог и нужно что бы при  .cat-parent:nth-child(1).active, каталог с классом .list-group менял background

Comment: возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: @ArtemFomkin, если вопрос решен, следует поставить галочку. Если одна задача решена и возникла новая, то следует создать новую задачу.

Comment: @MedvedevDev ну даже не знаю на сколько плохо продумывать наперёд такие небольшие, но сложные в отладке вещи. Я просто взял для себя за правило всегда пихать в обработчик события функцию с собственным this, ибо это верно в любой ситуации. Но для пущего сокращения и если игнорировать мою, так сказать, внутреннюю константу, то однозначно можно использовать и стрелочную функцию.

Comment: @MedvedevDev подскажите пожалуйста, где галочка, найти не могу

Comment: @Diskyp, в обработчиках логичнее использовать `event`, и получать контекст через `event.target`

Comment: @ArtemFomkin, слева от ответа где-то в районе "лайков" xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev нашел, спасибо)) по поводу Вашего кода, то я не смогу дать каждому меню data-color, так как это будет на вордпрессе, пункты меню это название каталогов

Answer (score 0):

Наверное лучше вынести определение цвета в data-attr, что бы упростить логику и повысить читаемость кода:

```js
/*
* Вариант с использованием data-attr*
*/
//$('.cat-parent').on('mouseover mouseout', e => {
//  $('header').css({
//    boxShadow: e.type === 'mouseover' ? `0 14px 24px ${$(e.target).data('color')}` : ''
//  });
//});

/*
* Вариант с массивом цветов
*/
const $catParent = $('.cat-parent');
const colors = [
  'rgba(82,56,115, 0.3)',
  'rgba(120, 134, 38, 0.3)',
  'rgba(218, 113, 0, 0.3)',
  'rgba(2, 84, 184, 0.3)',
  'rgba(73, 89, 21, 0.3)'
];

$catParent.on('mouseover mouseout', e => {
  $('header').css({
    boxShadow: e.type === 'mouseover' ? `0 14px 24px ${colors[$catParent.index($(e.target))]}` : ''
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

.cat-parent{
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<div class="cat-parent" data-color="rgba(82,56,115, 0.3)"></div>
<div class="cat-parent" data-color="rgba(120, 134, 38, 0.3)"></div>
<div class="cat-parent" data-color="rgba(218, 113, 0, 0.3)"></div>
<div class="cat-parent" data-color="rgba(2, 84, 184, 0.3)"></div>
<div class="cat-parent" data-color="rgba(73, 89, 21, 0.3)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте js, если можно решить проблему с помощью css. Предлагаю следующий вариант решения вашего вопроса

```
<div class="item-box">
  <div class="item-box__item">Блок1</div>
  <div class="item-box__item">Блок2</div>
  <div class="item-box__item">Блок3</div>
  <div class="item-box__item">Блок4</div>
  <div class="item-box__item">Блок5</div>
</div>
```

```
.item-box {

  &__item {
    max-width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    &:nth-child(1):hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 24px rgba(82,56,115, 0.3);
    }

     &:nth-child(2):hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 24px rgba(120, 134, 38, 0.3);
    }

     &:nth-child(3):hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 24px rgba(218, 113, 0, 0.3);
    }

     &:nth-child(4):hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 24px rgba(2, 84, 184, 0.3);
    }

     &:nth-child(5):hover {
      box-shadow: 0 14px 24px rgba(73, 89, 21, 0.3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: цвет надо менять у другого элемента, а не у того по которому происходит ховер, в этом и загвоздка.